# Finding JavaScript Elements on page: Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am currently trying to find an effective way to locate JS elements on a webpage and to then add my users data (username and password) to login with automatically. 
Im troubled finding a way to find the elements to work with, i know their names, and location, but can't get my code to do this.

I have gotten pretty much absolutely nowhere. Ive been struggling for a couple of days doing lots of reading and still find myself no closer.

Is it best to use `JSEvaluateScript`, or to use `webView.evaluateJavaScript?` I have literally trawled the internet and iOS Dev and SO and found only one sort of answer, but every time i run i get an error.

Using UIWebView

> JSEvaluateScript("credentials_table_unified_cell",
>   "credentials_input_text", "credentials_input_text", JSStringRef!,
>   NULL, 408)

Not sure how this would work to add my users Username to the form.

Using WKWebView

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('credentials_input_text').value = \(username.text!)", 
    completionHandler: {(result,err) in 
        print(result ?? "UN Element Not Found"); 
        print (err ?? "UN Element Found") })
```

From reading around this will add my users defined Username to the Element if found.

Any ideas where i'm going wrong or how to improve this?
I need to also use the same for Password, but i think ill be ok with the button click.

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated.  Using the evaluateJavaScript function of WKWebView is Apple's recommended approach.  I've been able to use this to manipulate the DOM, and to populate text fields, which seems to be be what you're trying to do.  One small error in your code is that you've forgotten to add the slash before referencing your variable in the String, i.e. "= (username.text!)".  You'll probably need to post your HTML in order to get an answer, along with details of what your HTML looks like after your evaluateJavaScript function has run, and any errors that are returned.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. I’ll post back when I get the basics working. Many thanks

Comment: I’m actually now not sure what you mean by I’m missing a \ ?

Comment: It looks like Zaki's edit to fix the formatting added the \.

Comment: The \ is already there